# I use the OpenMp in my code and get the error result

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, openmp

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(6)
            for (int m = 0; m < k_num; m++) {       
                Point(0, 0) = double(data3[j * 3]) - mean1[m].at<double>(0, 0);
                Point(0, 1) = double(data3[j * 3 + 1]) - mean1[m].at<double>(0, 1);
                Point(0, 2) = double(data3[j * 3 + 2]) - mean1[m].at<double>(0, 2);

                end = Point * inv[m] * Point.t();
                distance = sqrt(end(0, 0));
                if (distance < min && distance>0) {      
                    color = m;
                    class_success++;
                    //  color_map[i + left_y][j + left_x] = color; 
                    data2[(j + left_x) * 3] = lab_k[m][0];
                    data2[(j + left_x) * 3 + 1] = lab_k[m][1];
                    data2[(j + left_x) * 3 + 2] = lab_k[m][2];
                    data4[j * 3] = lab_k[m][0];
                    data4[j * 3 + 1] = lab_k[m][1];
                    data4[j * 3 + 2] = lab_k[m][2];
                }
            }
```

I try to traverse every pixel in the image, calculate the Mahalanobis distance between them and the color model.`(i,j)`is the point coordinates.I checked the code and all the variables should not be interrelated,but when i use openmp the result is different.Any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: "the result is different": Results of floating point multiplications in computers depend on the order. So it is ok that the result between single threaded and multithreaded computation can differ. But not sure whether this is the only reason here.

Comment: Thanks,but the results of the difference of classification vary widely,I think there may be problems in the assignment, the variable is private or shared? I am not sure.

Comment: Why not use [cv::Mahalanobis](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4493aee129179459cbfc6064f051aa7d) ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the variable is private,I declare the variable inside the body of the loop and get the right rsult.

```
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(6)
            for (int m = 0; m < k_num; m++) {       
                Mat_<double>end(1, 1);
                double distance = 1000;
                Mat_<double>Point(1, 3);
                ....
                }
            }
```